# is there a way to get better easing on keyframes in davinci resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve, keyframes

I'm trying to animate pngs of characters coming into frame when that person is talking but the easing that I can do when I right-click the keyframes is really bad. how can I make the easing more smooth because it still looks very linear? I can make a good, smooth ease in the curve editor but I don't want to do that to every keyframe in the video. what can I do?

I'm using resolve 17 studio

Answer (score 1):

Use Fusion inside of Resolve if you need better control over keyframes ease.  Fusion has the bézier curves you’d expect in an animation package.  Resolve’s Edit and Color pages are more simplified.

Comment: I usually use this plugin for after effect to help deal with keyframes.
http://aesweets.com/easy/

Basically, this plugin helps to create keyframe curves with clicks as it has many presets.

Do you know if there is any equivalent for Davinci?